# Django REST framework. Выгрузка модели в csv

Tags: django, csv, django-rest-framework

Есть следующая  модель данных:

```
class Student(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='student first name', max_length=64)
   last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='student last name', max_length=64)
   email = models.EmailField()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'student'

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

class Course(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   description = models.TextField()
   start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
   end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'course'

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class CourseParticipant(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='courses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, related_name='student_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    completed = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'course_participant'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course, self.student
```

И урлы:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('course', CourseAPIView.as_view()),
    path('course/<int:pk>/', CourseAPIDetailView.as_view()),
    path('student', StudentAPIView.as_view()),
    path('student/<int:pk>/', StudentAPIDetailView.as_view()),
    path('student/assigned_to_course', StudentAssignedToTheCourseAPIView.as_view()),
    path('student/assign_student_to_course', StudentAssignToCourse.as_view()),
    path('student/assigned_to_course/<int:pk>/', StudentAssignedToTheCourseDetailView.as_view()),
    path('student/report/<int:pk>/', StudentReportView.as_view()),
```

]

Мне нужно делать выгрузку данных в csv формате когда я перехожу по урлу

> path('student/report//', StudentReportView.as_view()),

Формат выгрузки такой:

- student full name
- number of assigned courses to the student
- number of completed courses by student

Например:

```
Test Student,10, 3
Test Student1,12, 1
Test Student2,5, 3
Test Student3,5, 4
```

Как я могу получить данные student full name и т.д. Помогите пожалуйста с вьюхой для этой задачи.

Comment: а еще у вас ошибка  `path('student/report//', StudentReportView.as_view()),` - 2 слеша подряд

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
full_name = "%s %s" % (student.last_name, student.first_name) # или канкатекацией

student_courses = CourseParticipant.objects.filter(student=student)

# number of assigned courses to the student
num_stud_courses = student_courses.count()
# number of completed courses by student
compleded_num_stud_courses = student_courses.filter(completed=True).count()
```

Для view вам надо воспользоваться [FileResponse](http://zetcode.com/django/fileresponse/) и, если не хотите хранить кучу файлов - [TemporaryFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619600/how-to-generate-temporary-file-in-django-and-then-destroy) для формирования файла и его отправки без сохранения

Почитайте [доку про работу с QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/) , в моем ответе использованы `filter` и `count` методы